# Recursively appending lists to the front of an element within a list

Tags: list, recursion, lisp, common-lisp, acl2

Using acl2, I am trying to create a function, "ins" that recursively appends the first argument (a list) to the front of each element in the second argument (another list), where

```
(ins (something) ( (a b c) (d e f) ...))
```

returns

```
( (something a b c) (something d e f) ...)
```

so a call to the function as such

```
(ins '((one thing)) '( ((this is)) ((something else)) ))
```

will give us

```
'( ((one thing) (this is)) ((one thing) (something else)) ))
```

I've come up with  non-recursive function that only works on arg2 lists containing a single element, checking if empty.

```
(defun ins(arg1 arg2)

  (if (equal arg2 nil) '() (list(append  arg1 (first arg2))))

)
```

When I try to come up with something recursive, so that it appends the first argument to all elements in the list of the second argument, the best I can do is

```
(defun ins (arg1 arg2)

  (cond

   ((equal arg2 nil) '())

   ((not(equal arg2 nil)) (ins (list(append  arg1 (first arg2))) (first(rest arg2)))

   )))
```

But I always get a nil no matter what, and I can't seem to figure out why. As such, I don't even know whether my recursive call is even correct. I just have a difficult time tracing non-trivial recursion.

Comment: To be clear, the second argument is a lists of lists and you want to prepend the first argument to each list in the list of lists right?

Comment: @PuercoPop Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
(defun ins (arg1 arg2)
  (if arg2
      (cons (append arg1 (car arg2)) 
            (ins arg1 (cdr arg2)))
      '()))
```

Comment: "when" isn't in the common-lisp package though. I will look it through regardless, thanks. I'm sure there's another way of writing it.

Comment: You can just use `if`instead in this case.

Comment: I don't believe if and when can be used interchangeably. While I don't know how "when" here works, if requires 3 arguments, where it's used as such- (if test then else). There are only 2 arguments used here.

Comment: Yes, I did. Told me I needed 3 arguments.

Comment: It's working! Just add a nil at the end as the last argument for if. Thanks so much! (or yes, in your case, an empty list)

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry for the hassle, I don't have ACL2 installed, just plain Common Lisp.